# Symfony Api Platform: Ordering results by custom entity method

Tags: php, rest, symfony, api-platform.com

In my Symfony Api platform project, I have an entity `Community` with a custom method `getTotalMembers()` that returns the number of members in the community. However, when I try to order my results, it doesn't work.

```php
#[ApiFilter(OrderFilter::class, 
      properties: ['id', 'name', 'totalMembers'], 
      arguments: ['orderParameterName' => 'order']
)]
```

```php
/**
 * @return int current number of users that are members of this community
 */
#[Groups(['community:read','community:read_list'])]
public function getTotalMembers(): ?int
{
    return $this->members->count();
}
```

Is there a simple way to make it work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a lot of struggle I was able to solve partially the issue with custom State processor on the many to many join relationship table. It calls method that adds or removes 1 from regular field that I can use for sorting.

```php
<?php

namespace App\State;

use ApiPlatform\Metadata\DeleteOperationInterface;
use App\Entity\Membership;
use ApiPlatform\Metadata\Operation;
use ApiPlatform\State\ProcessorInterface;
use Doctrine\ORM\EntityManagerInterface;
use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\Attribute\Autowire;

final class MembershipStateProcessor implements ProcessorInterface
{
    public function __construct(
        #[Autowire(service: 'api_platform.doctrine.orm.state.persist_processor')]
        private ProcessorInterface $persistProcessor,
        #[Autowire(service: 'api_platform.doctrine.orm.state.remove_processor')]
        private ProcessorInterface $removeProcessor,
        private EntityManagerInterface $entityManager,
    ) {
    }
    /**
     * @param Membership $data
     */
    public function process(mixed $data, Operation $operation, array $uriVariables = [], array $context = []): Membership|null
    {
        // decrease amount of members inside communities
        if ($operation instanceof DeleteOperationInterface) {
            $subreddit = $data->getSubreddit();
            $subreddit->setTotalMembers(isDelete: true);
            $this->entityManager->persist($subreddit);
            $this->removeProcessor->process($data, $operation, $uriVariables, $context);
            return null;
        }

        // increase amount of members inside communities
        $subreddit = $data->getSubreddit();
        $subreddit->setTotalMembers(isDelete: false);
        $this->entityManager->persist($subreddit);
        return $this->persistProcessor->process($data, $operation, $uriVariables, $context);
    }
}
```

The problem now, however, is that factories do not trigger this class and so entities made with factories aren't counted in, which hinders my ability to test this future.

Answer (score 1):

Consider changing the method to a regular field that recalculates when members change. Your current implementation is a very "hacky" way to approach the subject and might struggle in a production environment.

Comment: That's what I had before, but I encountered issues regarding persisting the changes.